# Can't find a way to output the chrome elements in c#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Trying to accomplish:
I'm trying to have the messagebox display the label element. But I'm getting the error posted. The reason for getting the label is trying to make sure the checkmark is checked correctly b/c the checkboxes results are always scattered. I'm trying to find the correct label then put a checkmark on the correct one.

[Image of the element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbZuk.jpg)

Full XPath:

```
//html/body/form/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/label]
```

XPath:

```
//*[@id="UserAdminForm1_chkListAccess"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/label
```

Tried:

```
    IWebElement up_names = null;

    up_names = caller.driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='UserAdminForm1_chkListAccess']/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/label"));

    MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(up_names), "Name", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
```

Error:

```
[OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*\[@id='UserAdminForm1_chkListAccess'\]/tbody/tr\[1\]/td\[1\]/label"}
  (Session info: chrome=96.0.4664.45)
  Source=WebDriver
  StackTrace:
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElementByXPath(String xpath)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.By.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<XPath>b__0(ISearchContext context)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.By.FindElement(ISearchContext context)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(By by)
   at Paya.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in \\KS\Project\Form1.cs:line 109
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, WM msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)][1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting

```
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*\[@id='UserAdminForm1_chkListAccess'\]/tbody/tr\[1\]/td\[1\]/label"}
```

exception, that could mean following :

1. This label is under an iframe.
2. This label is under a shadow-root.
3. You should not be on the new tab/windows launched by selenium.
4. Element was not rendered completely and you were trying to interact with it.

So, first you should check

```
//input[@id='UserAdminForm1_chkListAccess_0']//following-sibling::label[@for='UserAdminForm1_chkListAccess_0']
```

XPath is unique or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

if it is `unique` and the above `conditions` are false, then you could try the below code ;

```
var up_names = caller.driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='UserAdminForm1_chkListAccess_0']//following-sibling::label[@for='UserAdminForm1_chkListAccess_0']"));
```

And If you selenium version supports Explicit waits then

```
var up_names = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//input[@id='UserAdminForm1_chkListAccess_0']//following-sibling::label[@for='UserAdminForm1_chkListAccess_0']")));
```

Comment: Search result is 1:1; but it is still throwing the same error. Even with just //label[@for=‘UserAdminForm1_chkListAccess_0’] the result is 1:1.

Comment: iframe ? Did you check for that as well ? or was you redirected to this web element in a new window opened by selenium ?

Comment: Wow; it’s under so many frames.

Comment: You can switch it like this `new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)).Until(ExpectedConditions.FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.XPath("//iframe[@src='iframe src']")));`

Comment: Also, If You see nested iframes, then you will have to start switching from parent iframe and then down to the child/childs iframe first nd then only you would be able to interact with label.

Comment: Ok i don’t think it’s me. I think it has something to do with the addons. It used to work on the chrome v 85. Ever since I upgraded to chrome v96; none of my code works.

Comment: I would say the driver version should not bring inconsistency. Do you still see the same error ?

Comment: yeah same error. The only element I can pull is the first frame. Anything beyond that will go to the same error.

Comment: Can you share page link ?

Comment: it requires a login; however if you like I can share the source, but it'll be useless without being able to test it in real-time.

I cannot share the login as the site is confidential.

Comment: Source would be good enough, but do remember that if you use driver.page_resource to get the source, it would not contain iframe.